# Vmware Workstation in Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I am unable to get vmware workstation to work in Ubuntu 9.10. The same installer worked fine in 9.04. Installation is successful, but initialization is not. Does anybody know a fix?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.10
Release:        9.10
Codename:       karmic
```

VMware-Workstation-for-Linux-64bit-6.5.1-126130.x86_64

I don't think my key will work for version 7, sadly. I have a free 365 day student evaluation license.

Comment: Use VirtualBox: it's not worse from any point of view, and is FREE :) I also had problems when tried to install VMWare (used it while 'I WAS a PC'): it launched okay, but keyboard was not functioning at all :)

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't support paravirtualisation by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run VMWare Workstation on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic. In order to get it to install I had to follow [these directions](http://linux.aldeby.org/vmware-workstation-6-5-3-on-ubuntu-karmic-9-10.html) which basically state:

> [...] By default
>   the installer would freeze at the
>   “Configuring…” stage, never actually
>   completing.
>
> 1) The first step consists in
>   installing the program via terminal
>   and suppressing the warnings otherwise
>   eventually stucking the installer. [...]
>
> ```
> chmod u+x VMware-Workstation-6.5.3-185404.i386.bundle
> while true; do sudo killall -9
> vmware-modconfig-console; sleep 1;
> ```
>
> done in a separate terminal run:
>
> sudo ./VMware-Workstation-6.5.3-185404.i386.bundle --ignore-errors
>
> when the installer has finished, terminate the previous
>   command (while true…) with a CTRL+C or
>   simply close the terminal window.
>
> ```
> vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
> ```
>
> [...]
>   The mouse automatically ungrabs outside an area of 640 x 480 (vga resolution)
>   edit file `/etc/vmware/bootstrap` add at the bottom
>
> ```
> VMWARE_USE_SHIPPED_GTK=force
> ```

Answer (score 1):

WS 6.5.1 was released in November of 2008, before Ubuntu 9.10 was released so it definitely won't be supported. You should try upgrading to Workstation 6.5.4, which should be a free upgrade. According to [this](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software), WS 6.5.4 doesn't officially support Ubuntu 9.10 guests, but it is more likely to work than 6.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of VMWare Workstation?

I have:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.10
Release:    9.10
Codename:   karmic

$uname -r
2.6.31-15-generic-pae
```

with VMWare (md5sum):

```
a4286d08c2b302f1d3a164dcdc36c884  VMware-Workstation-Full-7.0.0-203739.i386.bundle
```

working OK.   I had problems with the last version of 6.5 on the 9.4 ubuntu.

Comment: I added some more info above.

Comment: What is your "uname -r" output?

Comment: $ uname -r


2.6.31-15-generic

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked about uname -a:

$ uname -a
Linux rover 2.6.31-15-generic-pae #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 10 16:12:10 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux